# Extension for Visual Studio Community 2019 to move class into a separate file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need an extension for MS Visual Studio Community 2019, that allows me to mark a block of C#-code and move it to a separate file. For example a class that is declared in the main method of my application.

I'm following a C# training class on Udemy and the instructor uses ReSharper for this task. Resharper will cost my just shy of 400€. As I'm unemployed trying to add C# to my list of skills I do not have 400€ to spend on this. A free extension would obviously be best for me. I don't like to set a max budget as I don't know what kind of price is fair for such an extension.

ReSharper does have a 30 free trial, but I'm not going with that option, since there is no way I can complete both the intermediate course and advanced course over 30 days.

I hope this question makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you learned your lesson. The best ideas is not to code like this in the first place :-)

Sorry, no offence, but while you are learning, it's best to learn good habits, not bad.

Anyway, I didn't come here to insult you, I came here to help you.

So I visited the Alternative To site and [this page](https://alternativeto.net/software/resharper/?license=free) lists

> [Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2012)
>
> A set of extensions to Visual Studio 2012 Professional (and above) which improves developer productivity.

use comment :

> "I will also download ***Move Class To File*** which is one of the main reasons for ReSharper."

Looks like that is what you want? Good luck

Answer (score 1):

With your example of *"a class that is declared in the main method of my application"* Visual Studio already allows you to do that natively (has done since VS2017), simply right click the name of the class then select **'Quick actions and refactorings'** and then **"Move type to xxxx.cs"**

[image]

Reference:
https://windowsdebugging.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/vs2017-moving-class-into-file/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, literally being "no extension is required, VS2019 already does this by default".